# JavaScript how to remove elements from one array which contains in second

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have misunderstood how to remove an element in an array which has a matching element to another array.

Example:

```
const items = ['first', 'second', 'third']
const secondItems = ['first', 'second']
```

Expected:

```
console.log(items) | 'third'
console.log(secondItems) | 'first', 'second
```

Hope some example how to achieve that.
Tried many times with two forEach or filter and checking statement but I always get the wrong result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112300/array-diff-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by the following:

```js
const items = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
const secondItems = ['first', 'second'];


const filteredBySecondItems = items.filter(function(item) {

  // For item in items array, check if there is a match
  // in secondItems. If there is no match, allow it
  // to be included in the returned list
  return secondItems.indexOf(item) === -1 

})

console.log(filteredBySecondItems) // [ 'third' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const items = ['first', 'second', 'third']
const secondItems = ['first', 'second']

console.log(items.filter(i => !secondItems.includes(i)))
console.log(secondItems.filter(i => items.includes(i)))
```

I don't exactly understand this expectation of yours though:

```
console.log(secondItems) | 'first', 'second
```

Can you elaborate on that in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

```
items.filter(x => !secondItems.includes(x))
```

Just tried in the browser console, it works.